# iPython code completion doesn't work in mac 10.9

Tags: ipython, code-completion

I found some post about this, but they don't work for me. Does anyone know how to  make the code completion work in mac ? Thanks

Comment: Code-completion in `IPython` is achieved by pressing TAB instead of CTRL-space. `Tab` is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Pycharm` IPython for code completion which is better than using `IPython` on your terminal.

Full tutorial is given here [Setting up IPython Notebook](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/using-ipython-notebook-with-pycharm.html)

Start typing in this cell, and notice code completion:
[image]

Comment: Excellent, this is what I want.